# How to handle HttpWebRequest C# with Tls 1.3

Tags: ssl, httpwebrequest, tls1.3

I am unable to connect to an HTTPS server (TLS 1.3) using WebRequest because of this error message:

**The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

The previous TLS version was 1.2 and with below code I could GET the page properly but as the page ssl upgraded to TLS 1.3 I got the error and also I cannot find any solution about it:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

In fact, I think it should be something like below:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
```

but there is not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that TLS 1.3 is not currently supported with SChannel (Windows TLS stack) and therefore also not with C#. But it would be a fool or have very special requirements who accepts exclusively TLS 1.3 today since support in commonly used libraries is still lacking. I rather suspect that your problem is something different but you don't provide enough information.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all SecurityProtocolType and I got an error for all of them. I want to GET a web page which has TLS 1.3. what further information do you need?

Comment: I mean I tried these:
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
        | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
        | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like TLS13 is supported now as part of the 4.8 .Net Framework

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netframework-4.8

However it is only supported on newer Window's OS versions (windows 11 and server 2022+), see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support) for full support details.

Comment: 4.8 declares the `SecurityProtocolType.Tls13` constant. Unfortunately, as .NET uses Schannel, the TLS 1.3 is not supported yet. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support, it should support TLS 1.3 on Windows Server 2022.

Comment: am facing a similar issue in some random Windows 7 machines. So If my .net app is upgraded to 4.8 version, would it be stable making the httprequests successfull?