# How to enable TLSv1.3 support in a .Net Framework running on pre Windows Server 2022?

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient, tls1.3, schannel

I am looking for a way to enable TLSv1.3 support on a .Net Application running on Windows Server 2012. While I knew .Net relied on the OS for portions of the TLS stack, I didn't realize that this made it so TLSv1.3 was largely [unsupported](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/4675#issuecomment-1545951274) for most (if not all) .Net Framework applications running on Windows Server before 2022.

While I have seen different version of the compatibility matrix, let's just assume a .Net 4.8 application on Windows server 2012 going forward. Is there any way to being TLSv1.3 support to this application? Specifically for the `HTTPClient` class?

*some literature suggests that using a userspace library, such as openssl, as a replacement is the best route to go. I have no found any examples though.*

Comment: The TLS version is provided by the OS, not .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: have u tired this https://support.centrestack.com/hc/en-us/articles/6959447480603-Enabling-TLS1-3-QUIC-on-Server-2022

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos right but a Userspace library such as openssl could replace it in a worst case scenario. So there is definitely *a* way, just trying to see what other ways people have come up with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle HttpWebRequest C# with Tls 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240173/how-to-handle-httpwebrequest-c-sharp-with-tls-1-3)

Comment: @LiamKelly that's not what I said. Both .NET Framework and .NET Core use the best TLS algorithm provided by the OS, not a third-party library. Unless the OS is configured to provide TLS 1.3, .NET Core can't use it. If you really want to use TLS 1.3 in earlier Windows versions you'll have to run your application inside WSL, essentially using the version provided by the Linux distribution. Or use a Linux VM

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that says that .NET uses whatever the OS provides